# find leftover area on a page html

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to find the leftover area on a web page? For example, I created a box which is YxZ dimension. And I'm trying to figure out if I could make any squares out of the rest of the  area. Is this feasible to do or it will take a bit of hackaround ?

Comment: Need more info. If this box is all there is, then it's easy to get the window width/height in JS and subtract Y/Z.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this it will in fact take a little bit of a "hack around". There is no JS method that will check your page automatically for left over space. As Ollie Ford suggested you can get the width and height of your element like so:

```
var pageHeight = $(document).height();
var pageWidth = $(document).width();

var elementHeight = $("#foo").height();
var elementWidth = $("#foo").width();

if (pageHeight > elementHeight) {
    // there is space for more elements height wise
}
if (pageWidth > elementWidth) {
    // there is space for more elements width wise
}
```